# Deploy julia application on google cloud build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, julia, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy a julia application on google cloud build. Using the below configuration files, I managed to successfully build the image on `cloud build` and deploy it on `cloud run`, however, when I try to access the application using the hosted url `https://backend.app` (coming from service under cloud run) it returns 500 error as shown in the pic below.

[image]

All the configuration files for my project are :

## Dockerfile

```
FROM julia:1.6.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
ENV JULIA_PROJECT @.
WORKDIR /home

ENV VERSION 1
ADD . /home

RUN julia deploy/packagecompile.jl

EXPOSE 9086

ENTRYPOINT ["julia", "-JApp.so", "-t", "auto", "-L", "src/backend.jl", "-e", "Backend.startapp()"]
```

## cloudbuild.yaml

```js
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - ./backend
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - 'gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname:$COMMIT_SHA'
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - run
      - deploy
      - backend
      - '--image'
      - 'gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--region'
      - us-global
      - '--platform'
      - managed
timeout: 3600s
images:
  - gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname
```

## cloudrun.yaml

```js
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: 'xxxxxxxx'
  selfLink: /apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/xxxxxx/services/backend
  uid: xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  resourceVersion: xxxxxxx
  generation: 8
  creationTimestamp: '2022-06-13T02:26:09.088993Z'
  labels:
    managed-by: gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
    gcb-trigger-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: us-global
  annotations:
    run.googleapis.com/client-name: gcloud
    serving.knative.dev/creator: xxxxxxxxxxx
    serving.knative.dev/lastModifier: xxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
    client.knative.dev/user-image: gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    run.googleapis.com/client-version: 387.0.0
    run.googleapis.com/ingress: all
    run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: all
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: app-backend-0032348-dob
      annotations:
        run.googleapis.com/client-name: gcloud
        client.knative.dev/user-image: gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        run.googleapis.com/client-version: 387.0.0
        autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: '1'
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '100'
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 300
      serviceAccountName: xxxxxxxxxxxx
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/project-id/github.com/username/appname:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        ports:
        - name: http1
          containerPort: 9086
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
  traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
status:
  observedGeneration: 8
  conditions:
  - type: Ready
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2022-06-13T09:02:43.268372Z'
  - type: ConfigurationsReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2022-06-13T09:02:36.523473Z'
  - type: RoutesReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2022-06-13T09:02:43.268372Z'
  latestReadyRevisionName: app-backend-0032348-dob
  latestCreatedRevisionName: app-backend-0032348-dob
  traffic:
  - revisionName: app-backend-0032348-dob
    percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
  url: https://backend.app
  address:
    url: https://backend.app
```

Please suggest a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance, looking forward to the responses.

## Update

Server logs from the cloud run:

```bash
Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall UNKNOWN[1008/0x3f0](0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0). 
It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. 
Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/linux/amd64/#UNKNOWN[1008/0x3f0] for more information.

fatal: error thrown and no exception handler available.

InitError(mod=:Nettle_jll, error=ErrorException("Artifact "Nettle" was not installed correctly. Try `using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()` to re-install all missing resources."))
error at ./error.jl:33

_artifact_str at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Artifacts/src/Artifacts.jl:551

jfptr__artifact_str_70148 at /home/AiSaraAI.so (unknown line)

_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2237 [inlined]

jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2419

jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1703 [inlined]

jl_f__call_latest at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:714

_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2237 [inlined]

jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2419

jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1703 [inlined]

do_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:670

#invokelatest#2 at ./essentials.jl:708

_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2237 [inlined]

jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2419

jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1703 [inlined]

do_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:670

invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:706

_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2237 [inlined]

jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2419

jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1703 [inlined]

do_call at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:115

eval_value at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:204

eval_stmt_value at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:155 [inlined]

eval_body at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:562

jl_fptr_interpret_call at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/interpreter.c:650

macro expansion at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Artifacts/src/Artifacts.jl:680 [inlined]

find_artifact_dir at /root/.julia/packages/JLLWrappers/QpMQW/src/wrapper_generators.jl:17

_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2237 [inlined]

jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2419

__init__ at /root/.julia/packages/Nettle_jll/LjWzs/src/wrappers/x86_64-linux-gnu.jl:10

_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2237 [inlined]

jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2419

jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1703 [inlined]

jl_module_run_initializer at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/toplevel.c:72

_julia_init at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/init.c:794

repl_entrypoint at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/jlapi.c:696

main at julia (unknown line)
__libc_start_main at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x4007d8)
Container called exit(1).
```

## Update 2

I tried to inspect the error as suggested by @VaidehiJamankar using `strace`. Since the error log is quite huge, last few lines of the logs are :

```
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [INT QUIT ABRT USR1 TERM], 8) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT QUIT ABRT USR1 TERM], NULL, 8) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [INT QUIT ABRT USR1 TERM], 8) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT QUIT ABRT USR1 TERM], NULL, 8) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] futex(0x29fe0938, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] futex(0x29fd88d8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] futex(0x29fe6fd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [pid   320] futex(0x29fd88d8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a072000[0m[91m)             = 0x2a072000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a093000)             = 0x2a093000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a0b4000)             = 0x2a0b4000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a0d5000)             = 0x2a0d5000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a0f6000)             = 0x2a0f6000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a664000[0m[91m)             = 0x2a664000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a685000)             = 0x2a685000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a6a7000)             = 0x2a6a7000
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91m[pid   320] brk(0x2a6c8000)             = 0x2a6c8000
TIMEOUT
ERROR: context deadline exceeded
Step #0 - "Build": [0m
```

Based on my search on this issue, it seems that `PackageCompiler` is unable to find cpu target. Please do correct me if i am wrong.

I tried building the image locally and push it to gcp and use it `cloud run` which resulted in simialr target:

```
ERROR: Unable to find compatible target in system image.
Uncaught signal: 11, pid=1, tid=1, fault_addr=6920.
Container terminated on signal 11.
```

To rectify I have tried passing `cpu_target` explicitly (as few have suggested) but it seems that it breaks the build on windows OS, only works with linux OS.

Look forward to responses on this matter

Comment: Error 500 is not very informative one. Have you checked your server's log file for the actual error message - in most cases it just should be there...

Comment: Please add the service's logs to your question. Have you tried running the container elsewhere (locally) to confirm that it works correctly?

Comment: Thanks @PrzemyslawSzufel for the response, i have added server logs.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin for the response, I have added server logs to the question.
Yes I am deploying the image locally built using same dockerfile, and it works perfectly locally but unfortunately i am bit lost on gcp configuration :)

Comment: The error log says that you have a problem with Julia package configuration.
When installed Julia packages download other files via the artifact mechanism - usually some precompiled code.

You should see the source of the problem in the `deploy/packagecompile.jl` as this file seems to be responsible for package installation. Please capture the logs of running  that file and post this too. Most likely the artifact binaries failed to install on the docker image.

Comment: The error mentions the `Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall UNKNOWN[1008/0x3f0](0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)` error which suggest a Sandbox container related error so may I ask you to provide the logs using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting/tracing-system-calls), so as to diagnose lower-level system calls that are not surfaced in Cloud Logging logs.

Comment: Were you able to derive the suggested logs for further diagnose lower-level system calls.Please use the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting/tracing-system-calls)

Comment: sorry for late reply, thanks for the response @VaidehiJamankar i tried running the execution using `strace` the logs are 100,000+ lines. Any idea how to post it here ?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel thanks for the response, is there a way to trace all the logs of a particular file in julia ? or you are also referring to `strace` method ?

Comment: Please add the error logs in question referring and mentioning the error message you received during execution.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar I have added the last lines of the results from `strace`, please do let me know if you require more results. 
I highly appreciate the response and suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @MohammadSaad, while I am investigating with the log, could you please confirm if you still have the issue.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar yes the issue still persist. I tried further tests and found that some artifacts (libraries) required to run the code are not getting installed and initialised properly on gcp. While on local testing (tried on multiple PCs) it seems to work.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar thanks for the help on this though, highly appreciate it!!

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar as artifacts are downloaded from the server in north america. Could it be that gcp has some network issue while accessing them?

Comment: Please let me know if recommendations and suggestions helped you rectify the error you had during the installation and artifacts .

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the logs and searching through the related documentation ,the first thing is to rectify the package installation issue . One of the error messages stated that some packages were not installed properly,so you may try reinstalling the packages.
Also,it looks like an application issue from the error
`` InitError(mod=:Nettle_jll, error=ErrorException("Artifact "Nettle" was not installed correctly. Try `using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()` to re-install all missing resources.")) error at ./error.jl:33 ``
This seems more suitable for julia developers to answer.
If this still does not work you may try to check if the issue is with an image built by cloud build or with cloud run being unable to run it,as the Cloud build just builds the image and cloud run runs it. Try using a Ubuntu base image and install julia with apt.
Hope that helps.